# Enabling entry box with associated chechbutton, but multiple rows of same

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to generate 4 entry boxes per row (Mins, secs, power & cadence, for a cycling app), and enable them with a checkbutton on same row, and have multiple rows of this.  I've tried a simple example I found, but cannot get it to work, any help much appreciated.

This is the code I've tried (only 2 entry boxes per row to test the idea), but failing to enable the entry boxes.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Python GUI Code")
root.geometry("400x400")

entries1 = []
entries2 = []
vars = []

def set_state(i):
    new_state = "disabled" if vars[i]==0 else "normal"
    entries1[i].configure(state=new_state)
    entries2[i].configure(state=new_state)
    
for i in range(10):
    ent1 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled").grid(row=i, column=0)
    ent2 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled").grid(row=i, column=1)
    entries1.append(ent1)
    entries2.append(ent2)

for key in range(10):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    cb = Checkbutton(root,command=lambda i=key: set_state(i)).grid(row=key,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

So, this is what I have so far, thanks for the help received, and I've edited it a bit to add a button & another small entry box.

I can now get() all the data from the active rows into a global list.
Some work to do to ensure the ADD only works if enabled entry boxes do have valid data in them. (I've changed the code to be a bit more explicit and done away with the "FIELD_NAMES" for my own clearer understanding...and might make spacing better with some thought?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Python GUI Code")
root.geometry("400x400")
mb_frm = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
mb_frm.grid(row=0, column=0)

mb_mins = []
mb_secs = []
mb_pwr = []
mb_cad = []
mb_vars = []
zdat = []       # This is the global that will hold ALL data from blocks, extra to this test-bed one.
mb_size = 5     # The number of rows required (probably about 15)?
                # Use less until fully debugged
def set_state(i):
    if mb_vars[i]==0:
        new_state = "disabled"
        mb_vars[i]=1
    else:
        new_state = "normal"
        mb_vars[i]=0
    mb_mins[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_secs[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_pwr[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_cad[i].configure(state=new_state)
    
mins    = Label(mb_frm, width=3, text="Mins").grid(row=0, column=0)    
colon   = Label(mb_frm, width=1, text=":").grid(row=0, column=1)
secs    = Label(mb_frm, width=3, text="Secs").grid(row=0, column=2)    
space1  = Label(mb_frm, width=1, text=" ").grid(row=0, column=3)
power   = Label(mb_frm, width=3, text="Pwr").grid(row=0, column=4)
space2  = Label(mb_frm, width=1, text=" ").grid(row=0, column=5) 
cadence = Label(mb_frm, width=3, text="Cad").grid(row=0, column=6)
Enable  = Label(mb_frm, width=5, text="Enable").grid(row=0, column=7)

for i in range(mb_size):
    mins = Entry(mb_frm, width=2, state = "disabled", disabledbackground="light grey")
    mins.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    secs = Entry(mb_frm, width=2, state = "disabled", disabledbackground="light grey")
    secs.grid(row=i+1, column=2)
    powr = Entry(mb_frm, width=3, state = "disabled", disabledbackground="light grey")
    powr.grid(row=i+1, column=4)
    cdnc = Entry(mb_frm, width=3, state = "disabled", disabledbackground="light grey")
    cdnc.grid(row=i+1, column=6)
    mb_mins.append(mins)   # Add the minutes to the list
    mb_secs.append(secs)   # Add the seconds to the list
    mb_pwr.append(powr)    # Add the power(W) to the list
    mb_cad.append(cdnc)    # Add the cadence to the list

for key in range(mb_size):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    mb_vars.append(var)
    cb = Checkbutton(mb_frm,command=lambda i=key: set_state(i))
    cb.grid(row=key+1,column=7)

def get_mb_data():
    global zdat
    local_data = []
    local_data.append("MBLK")   # Unique ID for this block
    for i in range(mb_size):
        if mb_vars[i] == 0:
            # Get the time, power & cadence for that row into a list
            # Only cadence can be blank, add an 'X' for blank cadence
            # to keep the list a multiple of 3 (but with extra "MB" at start).
            mins = int(mb_mins[i].get())
            secs = int(mb_secs[i].get())
            pwr  = int(mb_pwr[i].get())
            cad  = (mb_cad[i].get())
            time = mins*60 + secs
            local_data.append(time)
            local_data.append(pwr)
            if cad == "":
                local_data.append("X")
            else:
                local_data.append(int(cad))
    zdat.append(local_data) #Get the local
    
    # global zdat with their own unique ID.  A final "Build" button
    # will take all zdat data & build the workout for Zwift zwo (& maybe Garmin Fit)
    # Put this in root, otside of frame.
    debug = Label(root, text = zdat)
    debug.grid(row=1, column=0)
    debug.destroy

AddButton = Button(mb_frm, text="ADD", width = 23, command = get_mb_data)
AddButton.grid(row=mb_size+1, column=0, columnspan=9)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You already know how to enable or disable those entries based on the states of those checkbuttons, so you should know how to get the values from those entries based on the states of those checkbuttons.  I wonder why you cannot do it yourself.

Comment: Ah, I've done it now thanks.  I'd forgotten that the variables for the checkboxes get set to 0 when active & 1 when inactive in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your method chaining when creating the entries

```
    ent1 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled").grid(row=i, column=0)
    ent2 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled").grid(row=i, column=1)
```

You are setting ent1 to the return value of the `Entry.grid()` method, which is None.  You will instead need to split this over multiple lines - first creating the Entry, and then calling the grid method

```
for i in range(10):
    ent1 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled")
    ent1.grid(row=i, column=0)
    ent2 = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled")
    ent2.grid(row=i, column=1)
    entries1.append(ent1)
    entries2.append(ent2)
```

There is also currently an error in set_state when you are checking the current state:

```
new_state = "disabled" if vars[i]==0 else "normal"
```

`vars[i]` returns an IntVar object, so you need to get its value with `vars[i].get()`, and then you also need to toggle its value using `vars[i].set(new_value)`, or unchecking the checkbox won't disable the row.

This last part is going a bit beyond the original scope of the question, but I would also suggest that instead of tracking all of the entries for each row in disconnected lists, I would make a list or dict for each row containing all of the fields for that row, and then maintaining a single list containing all of those sublists.

I may have over optimized this solution, putting all of the fields and the checkbox for each row into a single dict, and swapping in a BooleanVar for the IntVar for the checkbox, but it works

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Python GUI Code")
root.geometry("400x400")

entries = []
FIELD_NAMES=["first", "second", "third"]

def set_state(i):
    if entries[i]["active"] == True:
        new_state = "disabled"
        entries[i]["active"] = False
    else:
        new_state = "normal"
        entries[i]["active"] = True

    for key, field in entries[i].items():
        if key == "active":
            continue
        field.configure(state=new_state)
    
for i in range(10):
    row = {}
    for idx, fieldname in enumerate(FIELD_NAMES):
        entry = Entry(root, width=3, state = "disabled")
        entry.grid(row=i, column=idx)
        row[fieldname] = entry
    state = BooleanVar(value=False)
    row["active"] = state
    cb = Checkbutton(root,command=lambda j=i: set_state(j)).grid(row=i, column=len(FIELD_NAMES))
    entries.append(row)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks for that.  I'll try it later next week.

Comment: As you say, might be over optimized; I'll be wanting to add header labels as follows:   [Mins : Secs  Pwr  Cad], and these 4/(5)? labels to align with the 4 entry widgets, then there'll be an ADD button to get all the data from the CHECKED entries into a global for later parsing (there are other simpler code blocks that will add to the global, this is one of the most complex).

Comment: @KevP  Fair enough.  The core problem was the method chaining issue, which was identified by the error in the terminal reporting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'`, and pointing to the line in `set_state`.  Fix that and then fix your toggle of the status value and you should be good to go.

Comment: OP wants 4 entry boxes per row, but not 3 entry boxes per row .

Comment: You should add this `FIELD_NAMES=['Mins', 'secs', 'power', 'cadence']` instead of `FIELD_NAMES=["first", "second", "third"]` To get 4 entry boxes

Comment: on line 32 and 36, add `grid` layout manager `.grid(row=i+1..)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra His example only had two per row. My three per row was just a demonstrative example of my recommendation for the data structure, as I assumed OP can figure out how to modify that to their needs.

Comment: Quetion:  Is there anything wrong with enabling/disabling this way:

def set_state(i):
    if entries1[i]['state'] == "normal":
        new_state = "disabled"
    else :
        new_state = "normal"
    entries1[i].configure(state=new_state)
    entries2[i].configure(state=new_state)
    entries3[i].configure(state=new_state)
    entries4[i].configure(state=new_state)

Comment: @KevP  That looks like it should work.   I would just recommend naming your column list variables something like `min_entries`, `secs_entries`, `power_entries`, `cadence_entries` instead of `entries1`, `entries2`, etc`

Comment: @nigh-anxiety  Was planning on doing that, the 1,2... etc is a hangover from when I was trying to get it to work, but a good reminder to do so. 

Answer (score 0):

Following @ nigh_anxiety's script.

You should add this `FIELD_NAMES=['Mins', 'secs', 'power', 'cadence']` instead of `FIELD_NAMES=["first", "second", "third"]` To get 4 entry boxes.

Add this between lines 26 and 26:

```
for num, text in enumerate(FIELD_NAMES):
    lbl = Label(root, text=FIELD_NAMES[num])
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=num)
```

on line 32 and 36, add `grid` layout manager `.grid(row=i+1..)`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks neat, still learning all about GUIs.